# Math and French practice floppies

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-software

A long time ago, at school, they used to provide us with some 5.25 inches floppies each year. The teacher used to boot Unisys PCs with some bootable floppies (I do not believe they had hard disks), we later insert these floppies and type `FR_3` or `FR_5` and similarly for Math `MT_3` or `MT_5` depending on the class for practice exercises. They were in French, it was more than 25 years but I remember in one of the Math floppies there was a match the corresponding answer using two Venn diagrams. Anyone, mainly from a French speaking place, came across these?

Comment: Was this in primary school, collège or lycée?

Comment: @StephenKitt what is equivalent to collège.

Comment: So this *wasn’t* in France? It would help to know the country, since educational programs in schools tend to be country-specific. (I know you’re looking for people who remember those specific programs, who therefore wouldn’t need to know what country this happened in, but knowing the country might help.)

Comment: I do not want it to appear in search engine results since the country did not have software development at the time and known for piracy. I think the floppies were obtained from a cultural mission and duplicated illegally. My bet is France or an European country.

Comment: Ah yes, in that case it’s the country of origin that matters ;-).